# Why is this the method of characteristics?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, boundary-value-problem, characteristics

The following question refers to ref. 1, the equation are numbered alike with a slightly different notation.
The author claims to solve a renormalization group (RG) equation - so the context is physical - using the [Method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) but I can't reconnect with the one I find in Mathematics literature (cf. e.g. the wiki link above). The equation to be solved is the following:
$$\left[\Lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial\Lambda}+\beta(g_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial g_0}-n\eta(g_0)\right]\Gamma_0(p_i; g_0, \Lambda)=0\tag{9.94}\label{9.94}.$$
They claim to apply the method of characteristics to solve it but here's what they do:

- Introduce a "dilatation parameter" $u$ and two functions theoreof $Z_\text{eff}(u)$ and $g_\text{eff}$(u) defined such that $$u\frac{d}{du}\left[Z_{\text{eff}}^{-n/2}(u)\Gamma_0(p_i;g_\text{eff}(u), u\Lambda)\right]=0\tag{9.97}\label{9.97}.$$
- They write explicitly the derivative in \eqref{9.97}
  $$Z_{\text{eff}}^{-n/2}(u)\left[\Lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial\Lambda}+u\frac{d}{du}g_\text{eff}(u)\frac{\partial}{\partial g_0}-n\cdot\frac{1}{2}u\frac{d}{du}Z_\text{eff}(u)\right]\Gamma_0(p_i;g_\text{eff}(u),u\Lambda)=0\tag{9.97a}\label{9.97a},$$
  which I labeled as \eqref{9.97a} because it is not on the book. Then, they claim that this equation is "compatible" (not sure what they mean) with \eqref{9.94} if the functions $Z_\text{eff}$ and $g_\text{eff}$ satisfy the following differential equations
  $$\begin{cases}
  u\frac{d}{du}g_\text{eff}(u)=\beta(g_\text{eff}(u))\qquad g_\text{eff}(1)=g_0 \\
  \frac{1}{2}u\frac{d}{du}\log Z_\text{eff}=\eta(g_\text{eff}(u))\qquad Z_\text{eff}(1)=1\end{cases}\tag{9.98-9.99}\label{9.98-9.99}$$
- Finally, using \eqref{9.94}, since it implies that the function inside the brackets is independent of $u$,
  $$Z_{\text{eff}}^{-n/2}(u)\Gamma_0(p_i;g_\text{eff}(u), u\Lambda)=Z_{\text{eff}}^{-n/2}(1)\Gamma_0(p_i;g_\text{eff}(1), \Lambda)=\Gamma_0(p_i;g_0, \Lambda)$$

So, is this really the method of characteristics? The starting step \eqref{9.97} and that compatibility conditions (which I don't understand yet) look very different from the standard method.

### Update

Given the comment by @NinadMunshi, who stated that the method of characteristics is all about writing things in the form
$$\text{directional derivative}=0$$
and then suggests that here we only did a clever substitution to do so, I think it's appropriate to be more specific with my doubts:

- Why the whole "compatibility" step? Is it just *one of the possible ways* to achieve the form \eqref{9.97}?
- The variables are $g$ and $\Lambda$, so I'd expect to have a curve $(g(u),\Lambda(u))$, instead of $(g(u),u\Lambda)$, unless in the second case we mean a *fixed* $\Lambda$, with some abuse of notation (as if your variables were $x$ and $y$ and you called the characteristics $x(s)=xs$ with constant $x$ instead of a more standard notation like $x(s)=x_0s$).
- The clever substitution has something unusual to it, though. Not only we have our function evaluated on the flow, but also $Z_\text{eff}$ multiplying it.

#### References

1. *Quantum Field Theory and Critical Phenomena*, Jean Zinn-Justin, 2021, fifth edition. Section 9.11.2-9.12, eqs. (9.91-9.101).

Comment: All the method of characteristics is saying is that solutions flow along level curves i.e. characteristics. This means we interpret all differential equations as being of the form "directional derivative equals zero". In this case we found with a clever substitution that the solution does not change in the $u$ direction because the $u$ directional derivative of $\Gamma$ was zero.

Comment: Hello, @NinadMunshi and thank you for your feedback. Do you have any comments on the "compatibility" step? What does being compatible mean here and why does it have to be so? I see a degree of arbitrariness in that step. Is it all just *one of the possible ways* to ensure that the solution does not change in the $u$ direction?

Comment: And there is an additional thing I don't understand about the flow here. The variables are $g$ and $\Lambda$, do I'd expect to have a curve $(g(u), \Lambda(u))$, instead of $(g(u), u\Lambda)$, unless in the second case we mean a fixed $\Lambda$  with some abuse of notation (as if your variables were $x$ and $y$ and you called the characteristics $x(s)=xs$ with constant $x$ instead of, say, $x(s)=x_0s$).

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/779492/renormalization-group-equation-and-method-of-characteristics).